# Compute covariance matrix given probability density fonction

Tags: probability, covariance-matrix

[image: The problem]

I'm given a probability function for 2 random variables and I have to compute the covariance matrix of the vector they form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are independent random variables as per the explanation, so the off-diagonal entries are 0. The diagonal entries are the respective variances. In order to compute the variance, you can benefit from [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).